# FileReader read CSV and put in HTML input value

Tags: html, jquery

As title,

I have a button to let user upload CSV file, and then I will use FileReader to get file,

it will use "for loop" to sort array, then put value in the input value,

but, when user want to edit the value which is in the input value,

ALL the value will be cleared, that's not a good user experience.

My code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Name</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_name" id="SelPitem2_name1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
　　</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Phone</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_phone" id="SelPitem2_phone1" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
　　</div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Email</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_email" id="SelPitem2_email1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
　　</div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Name</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_name" id="SelPitem2_name2" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
　　</div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Phone</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_phone" id="SelPitem2_phone2" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
　　</div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-4">
　　<div class= "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 text-left">
　　　　<h5 class="text-secondary">*Email</h5>
    </div>
　　<div class= "col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-8 text-left">
　　　　<input type="text" name="SelPitem2_email" id="SelPitem2_email2" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
　　</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var participate = [];

function csvUpload() {
    var volunteerQuntity = $('#_volunteerRequestQuntity').val();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
    　　var data = reader.result;

        // "CSVToArray" will convert data to array
        participate = CSVToArray(data);

        setCsvValue(participate);
    };
    reader.readAsText(document.getElementById("csv").files[0], 'BIG5');
}

function setCsvValue(participate) {
　　for(i = 1; i < participate.length; i++) {
    　　var SelPitem2_name = "SelPitem2_name" + (i);
        var SelPitem2_phone = "SelPitem2_phone" + (i);
        var SelPitem2_email = "SelPitem2_email" + (i);
        var SelPitem2_ID = "SelPitem2_ID" + (i);
        var SelPitem2_birthday = "SelPitem2_birthday" + (i);
        $("#" + SelPitem2_name).val(participate[i][0]);
        $("#" + SelPitem2_phone).val(participate[i][1]);
        $("#" + SelPitem2_email).val(participate[i][2]);
        $("#" + SelPitem2_ID).val(participate[i][3]);
        $("#" + SelPitem2_birthday).val(participate[i][4]);
　　}
}
```

Comment: side note: you can simplify the bootstrap class: `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4` equals to `col-md-4`

Comment: it depends on how you write `setCsvValue()`, but you didn't show the contents.

Comment: I update my code

Comment: In your code, there are no lines that will remove the values in your form. Any other form handler script you used? e.g. form validation?

Comment: Nope, I only use jquery to set vlaue